# The Tab-key doesn't works in the child controls

Tags: c++, winapi

The following is my winapi program that window contains 3 sets of controls:

1. The controls that created directly in the window
2. The controls in Group1
3. The controls in Group2

When I press Tab-key , it only traverse in set1. 
Why I can't switch to the child control of the group1 and group2 by Tab-key?

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT __stdcall   WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
        SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0, 0, 255));
        SetBkMode(hdcStatic, TRANSPARENT);
        return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void CreateEdit(const HWND &parent, const int &x, const int &y, const int &id) {
    CreateWindow(L"EDIT", L"", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, x, y, 200, 20, parent, (HMENU)id, NULL, NULL);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int __stdcall  wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine, _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wndclass{};

    wndclass.cbSize = sizeof(wndclass);
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 128, 255));
    wndclass.lpszClassName = L"test";

    RegisterClassEx(&wndclass);

    HWND hWndMainWindow = CreateWindow(
        wndclass.lpszClassName,
        L"test",
        WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_VISIBLE,
        100, 100, 500, 500,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ::ShowWindow(hWndMainWindow, SW_SHOW);
    ::UpdateWindow(hWndMainWindow);

    //Creating Controls~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    int x = 10, y = 20, id = 100;
    HWND    g1 = CreateWindow(L"button", L"Group1", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_GROUPBOX | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP, 0, 50, 220, 200, hWndMainWindow, (HMENU)++id, NULL, NULL);
    //Controls in Group1
    CreateEdit(g1, x, (y += 30), ++id);
    CreateEdit(g1, x, (y += 30), ++id);
    CreateEdit(g1, x, (y += 30), ++id);
    CreateEdit(g1, x, (y += 30), ++id);

    HWND    g2 = CreateWindow(L"button", L"Group2", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_GROUPBOX | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP, 260, 50, 220, 200, hWndMainWindow, (HMENU)++id, NULL, NULL);
    y = 20;
    //Controls in Group2
    CreateEdit(g2, x, (y += 30), ++id);
    CreateEdit(g2, x, (y += 30), ++id);
    CreateEdit(g2, x, (y += 30), ++id);
    CreateEdit(g2, x, (y += 30), ++id);

    //The controls that create  directly in the main window 
    y = 270;
    CreateWindow(L"static", L"Main Window Controls", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, 200, 30, hWndMainWindow, (HMENU)++id, NULL, NULL);

    CreateEdit(hWndMainWindow, x, (y += 30), ++id);
    CreateEdit(hWndMainWindow, x, (y += 30), ++id);
    CreateEdit(hWndMainWindow, x, (y += 30), ++id);
    CreateEdit(hWndMainWindow, x, (y += 30), ++id);
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        if (!IsDialogMessage(hWndMainWindow, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the focus doesn't move? You are using a `NULL_BRUSH` to render your Edit Controls, and maybe you aren't seeing the focus rectangle move.

Comment: The focus moves only to the controls of main window not to Groups' controls.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of this, but I don't think groupboxes are supposed to be the parents to the controls they seem to contain. I get this idea because of the way the WS_GROUP style works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two child windows that host "Group1" and "Group2" both need to be marked as "control parents" with the `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` style. This style means:

> The window itself contains child windows that should take part in
>   dialog box navigation. If this style is specified, the dialog manager
>   recurses into children of this window when performing navigation
>   operations such as handling the TAB key, an arrow key, or a keyboard
>   mnemonic

Change your code to create those windows as follows:

```
HWND    g1 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, L"button", L"Group1", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_GROUPBOX | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP, 0, 50, 220, 200, hWndMainWindow, (HMENU)++id, NULL, NULL);
HWND    g2 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, L"button", L"Group2", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_GROUPBOX | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP, 260, 50, 220, 200, hWndMainWindow, (HMENU)++id, NULL, NULL);
```

(As an aside, it seems wrong to make your windows children of the groupbox. They don't need to be - you can just position them inside it but make them siblings of it instead of children. The groupbox is specifically designed to work this way - I don't know how well it will work with the controls as children.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not creating a dialog box, your main window should be created with the [WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) style.

Make sure that you only place this style on your main window.  The child windows should not be using this style.

Comment: I used WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT style only for the Main window and the other controls have not this style,but it does not work yet.

Comment: @SaeidMo7 use [`CreateWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx) to use the extended window styles (first parameter), they won't work on `CreateWindow`

Comment: It's not the main window that needs it but the two child windows that host "group 1" and "group 2".